# i/o errors using npm install in vagrant on windows host

Tags: node.js, npm, vagrant, npm-install

Trying to install packages, I get a host of errors along the lines of:

```
(env)vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant/app$ sudo npm install browserify
/vagrant/app
├── babel@6.5.2  extraneous
└── react-dom@0.14.7  extraneous

npm WARN app No description
npm WARN app No repository field.
npm WARN app No license field.
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-45-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "--no-bin-links" "browserify"
npm ERR! node v5.8.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.1
npm ERR! path /vagrant/app/node_modules/.staging
npm ERR! code EIO
npm ERR! errno -5
npm ERR! syscall rmdir

npm ERR! EIO: i/o error, rmdir '/vagrant/app/node_modules/.staging'
```

Manually performing the failed operations such as the one above fixes the error but leads on to another i/o error.

Having read around, I have tried using:

```
npm install --no-bin-links browserify
```

Plus I already have this in my vagrantfile:

```
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
     v.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/v-root", "1"]
  end
```

Nothing I have tried so far has helped.

Thanks.

Comment: So you installing into mapper directory /vagrant/ ? Copypaste your file somewhere else and try to npm install there. This case you will understand if problem in windows permissions or not.

Comment: Hi. Yes so this fixed it. Seems it is a permissions issue. (I have now installed everything on host machine anyway, as there were other issues installing npm packages which cropped up after this).

Comment: @Sirrah did you ever figure out the way to fix this?  I am having the same issue and I do not want to install my project on a directory that is not shared with windows.  I am doing edits and I want to use my windows IDE (Webstorm).  In order to do this, I need to have the shared mount with the vagrant guest OS.